# Taking time to load pdf + rails2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.0

> I am using wicked_pdf for rails 2 app but when i generate bulk pdf it
>   is taking time to load helpers in the page.

Comment: Just to clarify, your post says rails 2 app, but the tag is ruby-2.0. If you are really using Rails 2 I would recommend you upgrade. But more importantly, could you post more details, perhaps? Show us the code that is being run, what have you tried, what were you expecting?

Comment: The application built long back.We are building an plugin for the code in that for bulk generation of pdf am getting loading error it is taking 20 minutes and also it is not taking other request during that time